# What would be Linux equivalent of GetProcessIoCounters?

Tags: linux, statistics, operating-system

Here's a link to Windows [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683218(VS.85).aspx).

Basically I would like to get similar data, but on Linux. If not all is possible, then at least some parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable `CONFIG\_TASK\_IO\_ACCOUNTING`, you will have the information available in /proc/<pid>/io. This is available since kernel 2.6.20, but not normally enabled by default (However, in Ubuntu 8.04 it seems like it is enabled).

You can read about the various data items in [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.26.5/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) in the kernel source tree. Especially section [2.14](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.26.5/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L2226) should be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `/proc/`*PID*`/io` - it's the current I/O accounting information of the process with PID.

Comment: What kernels is this supported under? What kernel configuration options are needed? I ask because a test machine on my desk does not show this one...

Comment: For me too... Running 2.6.25 here.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pseudo-files under `/proc/<PID>/`. Maybe you can find what you need there.

---

Look at `man 5 proc`, or failing that the kernel documentation. However, I don't see much that looks promising. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want getrusage()?  Not all fields are maintained under linux however.  Perhaps enabling the `CONFIG_TASK_IO_ACCOUNTING` will cause them to be maintained?